# Make a js code with a special format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get `date-type` and `date-title` in `div.Img` and make it as following format by jquery in the end putting it in a jQuery function, How is it?

This is `div.Img`:

```
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" date-title="manual 1st title"></div>
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg" date-title="2nd title"></div>
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg" date-title="3rd title"></div>
```

This is `my format`: i want get in result as fllowing fomat of `date-type` and `date-title` in `div.Img`, with `{`  `}` and `,`.

```
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',
        title : 'manual 1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',
        title : '2nd title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',
        title : '3rd title'
    }
```

Please give me a example in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom attribute should be `data-*` prefixed not `date-*`

```
<div class="Img" data-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" data-title="manual 1st title">1</div>
```

Then [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) can be used in conjunction with [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2)

```
var arr = $('div.Img').map(function (elem) {
    return {
        href: $(this).data('type'),
        title: $(this).data('title')
    }
}).get();

console.log(arr);
```

[**Fiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/oy32tuhL/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code snippet sample.

```js
function getDivInfo($div) {
  return {
    "href": $div.attr("date-type"),
    "title": $div.attr("date-title")
  };
}

$(function() {
  var div_info = [];
  
  $('div.Img').each(function() {
    div_info.push(getDivInfo($(this)));
  });
  
  console.log(div_info);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" date-title="manual 1st title"></div>
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg" date-title="2nd title"></div>
<div class="Img" date-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg" date-title="3rd title"></div>
```

Please note that custom attributes should begin with `data-` and not `date-`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **.map()** in Jquery.

> The $.map() method applies a function to each item in an array or
>   object and maps the results into a new array

```
var res = $(".Img").map(function() {
    return {"href":$(this).attr('date-type'),
            "title":$(this).attr('date-title')
           }
}).get();

 console.log(res);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfpgwfzw/)